# What are the headphones like on the British Airways Boeing 787 economy?

Tags: air-travel, british-airways, in-flight-services

What are the headphones like on the British Airways Boeing 787 economy?

I have lost my noise cancelling headphones so I want to know.

Comment: I don't know what answer you're looking for, but don't expect anything great from airline-supplied headphones in economy.

Comment: Sure, let's close this perfect travel question, and have more questions about visas!

Comment: Almost certainly crap, and it won't depend on what kind of plane you're on. They have to be cheap enough that they can be thrown away after one use.

Comment: @Fattie - this is a terrible question for Stack Exchange as it is opinion based and unpredictable.

Comment: Our opinions don't change the headphones supplied by British Airways. Voting to reopen the question.